# How to highlight text resulting from dynamic model in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am displaying schedule and i want to highlight currently playing item in the schedule. The data in schedule is returned using dynamic model binding. I am not using any grid like telerik or something. Data is simply populated into div. Any help will be appreciated. Is it possible to do via controller?

Comment: Can you give bit more clarity around your question? You have list of schedules and you want to highlight present schedule on UI with different style, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [page.](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)  I believe this will help you out.  Basically you will need to have the model set to a group and then you can call the active item through javascript and perform the highlighting that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to highlight currently playing item in the schedule

Here goes my solution using a simple ternary operator on the view.

Lets say if you have a simple model like this -

```
public class ScheduleViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduleTime { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller action is returning List of Schedule times as shown below. Notice we have different dates in the List.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ScheduleViewModel> sch = new List<ScheduleViewModel>();
        sch.Add(new ScheduleViewModel() { Name = "Sch1", ScheduleTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) });
        sch.Add(new ScheduleViewModel() { Name = "Sch2", ScheduleTime = DateTime.Now });
        sch.Add(new ScheduleViewModel() { Name = "Sch3", ScheduleTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) });
        return View(sch);
    }
```

Then on the View, we can have following code -

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC.Controllers.ScheduleViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ScheduleTime)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ScheduleTime, item.ScheduleTime.ToString(), new { style=item.ScheduleTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date ? "background:green;" : "background:red;" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

So in above code we are using a simple Ternary operator to allot a particular style to the present date schedule. Display will be like shown below -

[image]

To have DateTime comparision, you can have something like this -

```
 @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ScheduleTime, item.ScheduleTime.ToString(), new { style = item.ScheduleTime == DateTime.Parse("2/18/2014 10:00:00") ? "background:green;" : "background:red;" })
```

That would give you following output -

[image]

To get only time comparision -

```
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ScheduleTime, item.ScheduleTime.ToString(), new { style = item.ScheduleTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == new TimeSpan(10,0,0).ToString() ? "background:green;" : "background:red;" })
```

But I dont think you need ONLY time comparison, you need to compare Date and time (as shown above) to get your requirement done.

Comment: What if i have multiple items for single date and among that i want to highlight item as per current time?